# Can I skip step in Bonita workflow?

Tags: bonita

I used Bonita workflow 5.6

Say you have a Process with 5 steps.
On Step 3 there is an error because some database was not available, for instance.
Does a way to skip step 2 to 4 directly through User XP or bonita api?

Answer (score 1):

Use Exceptions. If memory serves me correctly, they're the red circle with a thunder icon. This way you can define a transition to occur when something fails.

In your case, put an exception in step 2 and draw a transition from that exception to step 4.